# Do capacitors increase voltage?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

Just got a (220<-->12-0-12) transformer hooked up with a bridge rectifier and it measured 13 volts DC output from rectifier, but when I added a 1uF capacitor it just jumped up to 20 volts, and same reading(20 volts) from a 0.1uF capacitor, how is that even possible!?

Note: Nothing is connected in the circuit more than a transformer and a bridge rectifier in the first case, and only a capacitor added in the second case along with the voltmeter.

Comment: As Tom answered, the difference is RMS voltage versus peak voltage. Peak voltage would be approximately 1.4 times the RMS voltage with a proper rectified sine wave, so your measurements are somewhat off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\$V_{rms}\$ vs. \$V_{peak}\$. The peak voltage is \$\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4\$ times larger than the average (RMS) voltage.

If you put a capacitor on a rectified AC waveform it will smooth out the supply. If there is no load, it will smooth it out to around the peak voltage of the supply.

A 220V AC supply is 220V RMS, which is equivalent to 311V peak. If you bring that down to 12V AC, that is equivalent to about 17V peak.

As to how you got 20V, either your meter is dodgy (unlikely) or the supply voltage is higher than you thought, or the transformer is not the ratio you think it is.

---

If you add a load, the voltage will drop because the average voltage supplied is the RMS value - the capacitor can't sustain a current at the peak voltage because that would require it to deliver more power to the load than is being delivered by the transformer.

That the rectified supply is varying between 0 and \$V_{peak}\$ with the average voltage being \$V_{rms}\$. If you are drawing a current, the capacitor will smooth this out to be around \$V_{rms}\$, but if you aren't drawing any current, then it will keep getting "topped up" with charge until it reaches the peak voltage. As a demonstration of this, try putting, say, a 1k resistor at the output of your supply, you should see the voltage drop.

Comment: does that mean it won't do that if a load is connected? because it can get damaged if it is connected to 20VDC since it only needs 12VDC

Comment: can you just please give me a brief explanation of what is RMS, to help me undersand?

Comment: @user3407319 RMS means "root mean squared". Essentially it is nothing more than a way of measuring the "average" voltage of an AC waveform.

Comment: thank you I got it now, what about the 1st question?

Comment: @user3407319 see my edit.

Comment: This peak voltage is capable of destroying components which coudn't resist more than 12V right? if so, how we can save the components?

Comment: @Rajesh.k by using a regulated power supply rather than a unregulated transformer.

Answer (score 3):

The "220VAC" and "12VAC" are RMS ("average") values. That is normally how Alternating Current is measured and specified.

By adding rectification and capacitive filtering, you have converted the RMS AC voltage into "peak" DC voltage.  This is completely normal and predictable.

For a bridge rectifier and "capacitor-input" filter we typically use the square-root of 2 (1.414) as the multiplier to predict the resulting DC voltage.  Of course other factors enter into the equation in Real Life.  For example, you won't see the same voltage under load as you are measuring "open-circuit".

Answer (score 1):

When speaking of AC voltage, we normally refer to the RMS value - a "sort of" average.  The peak AC voltage will be about 1.4 times the RMS value.

When you rectify an AC voltage you will get successive half-waves of the sine wave - this should (I think) give an apparent DC voltage about equal to the RMS value of the AC.

When you add a capacitor, the capacitor will charge to the peak voltage each half-cycle, and, if there is any load current, will discharge between the AC peaks.  With no load, you should measure a DC voltage equal to the AC peak voltage (possibly minus 0.7 volts or so lost in the rectifier diodes).

It appears that your transformer is producing a bit more than the advertised 12-0-12 volts - not uncommon if you are not drawing any significant load current.

Answer (score 0):

A load placed on the rectifier/capacitor network should drop the peak voltage into the RMS range, which, as stated above, is the average voltage.  If you look at a sine wave you will notice that the wave form is “thinner” at the top of the wave so that it does not carry the same amount of power as a square wave.  A sine wave graph represents both time and voltage.  A minuscule amount of time passes before the peak voltage is achieved and immediately after the peak the voltage begins to fall as the time moves forward, in voltage rise and fall.  A square wave would fill the entire capacity and have more total power.  If we were to measure volume instead of voltage, we would be filling only 70 percent of the potential capacity, so in the same vein we have only 70 percent of actual voltage as compared to peak voltage.  A capacitor does not differentiate between the two and it absorbs peak voltage until a demand is placed upon it, in which the peak voltage is quickly consumed, leaving the true voltage, which is the root means squared, which is approximately 70 percent of peak.  The only problem comes when the the capacitance is very high and the load at startup is too small to consume the excess peak voltage, with the result that, temporarily, at least, the voltage remains too high for sensitive equipment. The “more is better” does not work in every case.  Find the capacitance value you need to diminish ripple and go no higher, and also save the expense of unnecessary extra capacitors.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying here. "measure volume instead of voltage"? What potential capacity? I disagree with your saying the RMS is the true voltage, incidentally.

Comment: If the area was a grain bin, for example, only 70 percent of the bin would be filled with grain.  With the sine wave, only 70 percent of the total potential electricity is available, whereas in a square wave 100 percent of electricity is available.  You may disagree with me but RMS  is still, nonetheless, the true voltage and all AC electrical devices are measured in RMS, not peak to peak, with the exception of highly inflated claims of amplifier output power.  The true voltage is what is measured after a load is placed on a circuit.  RMS is an average voltage and is mathematically correct.

Comment: What do you mean by potential electricity? I feel like you have some kind of misconceptions here.... Anyway, what I disagree with in particular is the idea that there is a "true voltage" at all.

Comment: Hearth, you need to understand the difference between peak to peak voltage and RMS voltage.  I think you have the misconception, but we will not go into that.  Simply put, when you put a load on the capacitor voltage source the voltage will drop.  RMS is the average of the voltage.  By true voltage, what is meant is the RMS.  The potential electricity is the amount of electricity available to do the work.  You cannot sustain a peak to peak voltage under a load.

Comment: I am not saying you can either. But "amount of electricity" is meaningless, and "true voltage" is also meaningless--you need to define your terms. I'm well aware of the difference between peak voltage and RMS voltage, but *both of these are only useful in specific contexts*. Neither is more real than the other. And in fact you can't even give a good definition of RMS voltage for an aperiodic signal.